# Comma placement inline math

Tags: article-writing

In the following sentence

> If all $f(x_j), j=1,\dots,N$ are positive, then ...

Do you think there should be a comma after the $N$? I always considered the math as a single unit and read the sentence as

> If all [MATH] are positive, then ...

Accordingly I only put commas when the surrounding sentence required them, as in

> Given $f(x_j), j=1,\dots,N$, our goal is to ...

I am asking because I observed a lot of authors not following my thinking. However, there are also some that more or less do put the commas as I do, so I wondered if you know about guidelines regarding this question or simply have a definite opinion about it.

Comment: Personally, I like to treat my math as if it's part of the sentence. Also I don't like to have two different math statements next to each other without words. I'd do something like "Given $f(x_j)$, where $j=1,\ldots,N$, our goal is to..."

Comment: What about the first example? "If all $f(x_j)$, where $j=1,\dots,N$, are positive" breaks the sentence apart. "If all $f(x_j)$ are positive, where $j=1,\dots,N$" breaks the math apart.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "If all $f(x_j)$, where $j=1,\ldots,N$, are positive", but you can also do "If $f(x_j)$ is positive for all $j=1,\ldots,N$"

Comment: The two phrases are grammatically different. In the first, there *shouldn't* be a comma after $N$; in the second, there *should* be one after "positive". Forget about whether there's math present: this would be true if the sentences were "If each of John, Mary, and Joe are happy, then ...", and "Given that we have amassed all the data, our goal should now be to...".

Comment: @BrianO That they are gramatically different is exactly the reason of my usage so far. However, an argument for a comma after $N$ in the first sentence is: $j=1,\dots,N$ is a restrictive clause initiated by a comma and should thus be terminated by a comma. I don't know the grammatical terms, but an equivalent without math would be: "If the kids,  and by kid I mean everyone under the age of 18, are happy, then ..."

Comment: But "If all $f(x_j), j=1, ... N$" isn't a restrictive clause, it isn't even a clause. You don't have a full clause until you get to the end of "are positive", where of course a comma *is* required. It reads badly and goes "bump* to have a comma after $N$. You wouldn't write "If Moe, Larry, and Curly, are funny, then ...", and you wouldn't write "If the integers, are rationals, then...".

Comment: What I am saying is that the $ j=1,\dots, N $ can be regarded as a restrictive clause

Comment: @BrianO I believe the OP is saying that you can read the sentence as "Given $f(x_j)$, where $j=1, ... N$, - our goal is to...".  In this case the comma is clearly recommended.

Comment: @JackM, I agree that in the example you just gave, in the presence of "where" a comma is called for. But that's the 3rd highlighted fragment, not the first.

Comment: @BrianO The first fragment can be read that way as well, imagine there's an implicit "where" or "with" after $f(x_j)$.

Comment: @JackM I can imagine all sorts of things being there which in fact aren't. As it stands, it's at best awkward, worse, and arguably wrong to put a comma there. However, I don't want to flame about this.

Comment: @BrianO I found "Mathematics into Type" by the AMS (available online), which says in Section 2.6.3 that the comma always belongs there.

Comment: @Bananach Do you have a link? I only found a version behind a paywall.

Comment: Does ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf work?

Answer (score 0):

To summarise those comments with which I agree: the following are preferable.

> If all $f(x_j)$ are positive (as $j$ ranges from $1$ to $N$), then…
>
> If for all $j$ with $1 \leq j \leq N$ we have $f(x_j)$ positive, then…

A little more clumsy:

> If all $f(x_j)$ (where $j = 1, \dots, n$) are positive, then…